# Working with nested resources in Rails 4.2.5, Is it possible to gather all child elements and display them on the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, parent-child

Being new to Rails I've still yet to understand params and the controllers affect on my entire app. I have problems with accessing @variables accross the entire program. For example while working with a parent resource controller when I try to define @child in the controller, I often get the error "Couldn't find Project with 'id'="  or "undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :find_campaigns, only: [:index]

  def index
    if params[:search]
      @projects = Project.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @projects = Project.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.build
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    # @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      redirect_to @project, notice: "Successfully created new Project"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @project.update(project_params)
      redirect_to @project, notice: "Project was Successfully updated"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    @random_project = Project.where.not(id: @project).order("RANDOM()").first
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :location, :goal, :investor, :description, :image, :category)

  end

  def find_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def find_campaigns
    @campaign = @project.campaigns.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The above is my child controller.  If I add a private method called find_projects (which is my parent object)  is there a way to access all children from all projects and display them on one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would loop through each Project and access its children. Start by removing your `find_campaigns` method and `before_action :find_campaigns` as they are not needed.

Open up `app/views/projects/index.html.erb`

```
<% if @projects.any? %>
  <ul class="projects">
    <% @projects.each do |p| %>
    <li>
      <h3><%= p.name %></h3>
      <% if p.campaigns.any? %>
      <ul class="campaigns">
        <% @p.campaigns.each do |c| %>
        <li><%= c.name %><li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

However when doing this you need to take care since you are cause what is called a `N+1` query where every iteration of `@projects.each` will do a seperate SQL query to fetch the children which is really slow.

We can avoid this by using `includes` so that the campaigns are loaded in one sweep:

```
def find_project
  @project = Project.includes(:campaigns).find(params[:id])
end
```

You might want to look at [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) as it has some pretty nice tricks for using partials to clean up the loop above.

Comment: it's right but it needs a <% end %>  right before </ul> to close the inner method

Comment: Thanks @DauvO, saw this code this morning and realized coding when you can't sleep does'nt always produce great results...

Comment: No problem, minor things happen no big deal.  Hate to be a beggar, but if you have the time to check out another question of mine, I would appreciate it. You seem to know what you are doing. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096668/how-can-i-link-to-a-nested-child-from-outside-the-parent-element-in-rails-4)