# How can I link to a nested child from outside the parent element in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, link-to, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Ok, my situation.  I have a nested resource of

```
    resources :projects do
        resources :campaigns
    end
```

I want to make a view with controller with

```
    resources :portfolios
```

I want to make a <% link_to %>  that listed all campaigns which I can do, but when I try to route the path i can't make it link to a campaign.

Example: in my **portfolios/view/index.html.erb**

```
<% @projects.each do |p| %>
  <% p.campaigns.each do |c| %>
    <div class="container" >
      <div>
        <%= link_to ( image_tag c.image_camp.url(:thumb)), p %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h3 style=""><%=link_to c.title, p %></h3>
        <h4><%= c.end_date %></h4>
        <h4><%= c.project_end %></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4><%= c.project_end %></h4>
        <p><%= link_to "read more", p %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The above example links to the @project, I have tried putting 'c' in hopes it will link to the @campaign that I am obviously getting information from, but when I do I get the error

```
  undefined method `campaign_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000cc74b68>:0x0000000ef964c0>
```

I've also tried project_campaigns_path(@project, campaign)  and every other combination I could think of.

```
    undefined local variable or method `campaign' for #<#<Class:0x0000000cc74b68>:0x0000000ae94cd8>
```

I feel the problem lies in the portfolios_controller and that I have yet to understand how the controller affects routes and how to access those variables.

```
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @projects = Project.all.order('created_at DESC').includes(:campaigns)
  end
end
```

I assumed that @projects and @campaigns are both found as I am able to display everything on the portfolio/view, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `Project` and the `Campaign` to the `link_to`. It will then know how to route to the nested resource.

Comment: Could you explain more, I'm new and from my explanation I have tried `<% link_to c.title, project_campaigns_path(@project, campaign)` which is what I think you are saying, and it gives an error of `undefined local variable 'campaign'` and if i do `<% link_to c.title, project_campaigns_path(@project, @campaign)` I get the error `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"campaigns", :project_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:project_id]`

Comment: `<% link_to c.title, project_campaigns_path(@project, campaign) %>` is almost right you need `<% link_to c.title, project_campaigns_path(p, c) %>`. The reason you want to use `p` and `c` is because you are iterating over the projects and the campaigns for each prospective project. The `each` iterator passing the element into the block in the variable you set between the pipes `|p|` and `|c|`. So in this case `p` and `c` are the instances of those objects which rails uses the ids of to construct the url.

Comment: That seems to work, but it takes me to the campaigns index page.  instead of the show page.  When I look in the address bar it show this `http://localhost:3000/projects/26/campaigns.7` instead of `http://localhost:3000/projects/26/campaigns/7` the only difference being .7 is not a path and I need /7   Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: Actually, I see the difference is Project_campaign for /7 route and project_campaigns *plural* for the .7 route.   Thank you for your help, you were spot on.